# GmailApp createLabel vs getUserLabelByName

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't want to assume that label **foo** exists.

Must I do...

```
var foo = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("foo");
if (foo == null) {
  var foo = GmailApp.createLabel("foo");  
}
```

Or is it enough to do the below (which seems to work!)...

```
var foo = GmailApp.createLabel("foo");
```

Questions

1. Which of #1 or #2 are correct?
2. Why ever do #1 if #2 works?
3. Is there a third better way to write the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `GmailApp.createLabel("Label_Name")` should suffice in creating a new label. Even if a Label in that name is present.

So,

1. Both are correct, in the sense, that both are working.
2. `#1` is redundant. Then why bother to put those unnecessary checkings.
3. It's pretty simple and efficient. Why are you looking for better
   options? It's documented
   [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createLabel(String)).

For deleting a label you have to use the first method of course:

```
// have to get the label by name first
 var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("FOO");
 GmailApp.deleteLabel(label);
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed a second opinion.